# How to switch currency programatically using WooCommerce Multilingual & Multicurrency plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I need to be able to switch currency on WooCommerce site by adding specific link. On client's site is installed WooCommerce Multilingual & Multicurrency by OnTheGoSystems.

I have something like this at the moment:

```php
add_filter( 'wcml_client_currency', 'abc_client_currency' );
function abc_client_currency( $currency ) {
    if( !empty( $_GET['country'] ) ) {
        switch ( $_GET['country']) {
            case 'US':
                $new_currency = 'USD';
                break;
            case 'PL':
                $new_currency = 'PLN';
                break;
            default:
                $new_currency = 'EUR';
                break;
        }

        $settings = get_option( '_wcml_settings' );
        $currencies = $settings['currency_options'];
        $currency_codes = array_keys( $currencies );
        if( in_array( $new_currency, $currency_codes ) ) {
            return $new_currency;
        }
    }
    return $currency;
}
```

It works on the very first pageload (as long as there is `?contry=XY` in url). I know I could possibly save currency into a cookie/session and keep using this method, but that doesn't seam right. I would like to properly switch the currency.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you have some sort of dropdown list for selecting between currencies:**

```
<ul id="curr_switcher">
    <li class="country" data-country="US">USD</li>
    <li class="country" data-country="PL">PLN</li>
    <li class="country" data-country="FR">EUR</li>
</ul>
```

I'd use some simple jQuery hooked to the wp_footer action (NOT wp_head as jQuery will likely not be loaded yet) to redirect to the same page/location with correct variable on user click - just hook it to wp_footer action to load on all front-end pages :

```
<?php
    add_action('wp_footer', function () { ?>

        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                // .country on click
                $('.country').click(function(e) {

                    // prevent default behaviour
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // retrieve country code
                    var country = $(this).data('country');

                    // retrieve current location pathname
                    var current_loc_path = window.location.pathname;

                    // append currency argument to pathname
                    var new_loc_path = current_loc_path + '/?country=' + country;

                    // use location replace to redirect page with correctly appended currency as argument
                    window.location.replace(new_loc_path);

                });
            });
        </script>

    <?php }); ?>
```

So in a nutshell you're retrieving the current browser window location path, appending the selected country to that path on click, and then basically reloading the page (technically a full redirect, but let's not split hairs here).

Note that this is probably not the most "technically correct" way of doing it - there are probably other way more involved ways of achieving the same thing - but my tendency is always towards finding the simplest solution, as long as it works and your code is properly commented for future reference!

***Note also:** this will likely not work past the current page - probably a good idea to append the country argument to all links you wish to load the correct currency for.*

Hopefully the above get you started in the right direction.